# Why quantile does not shows different results?

Tags: r

I am trying to use this solution here

[How to rank based on ecdf in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217551/how-to-rank-based-on-ecdf-in-r)

```
 dat[, .(quant = quants, val = ecdf(dist)(quantile(dist, quants))), by = rowval]
```

This gives diffent results for each rowval

However, when i apply it to my data, I always got the same output

example:

```
     ecdf(gg)(quantile(gg, quants))
     ecdf(ff)(quantile(ff, quants))
```

Why I am getting the same for both ff and gg?

Comment: Where is `quants` defined? What exactly are you trying to do? By using `quantile()` inside the `ecdf()` you are basically doing the inverse operation. Most likely you would be getting values very close to whatever values of `quants` you pass in. They basically cancel each other out.

Comment: I am referring to that solution. Why it worked for that specific example, but not my data. I am getting mad

Comment: Thanks, please see the solution in that link .

Comment: When I run your code, those two expressions produce different outputs. What are you expecting?

Comment: @r2evans Can you please post your output? As me, I got similar output, see my comment below

Comment: `all.equal(ecdf(gg)(quantile(gg, quants)), ecdf(ff)(quantile(ff, quants)))` yields `[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.01136364"`. They look the same but they are not. If you run `ecdf(gg)(quantile(gg, quants)) - ecdf(ff)(quantile(ff, quants))` you'll see that there are some minor differences. This to me suggests that the `ff` and `gg` datasets are similarly (not identically) distributed.

Comment: In the previous question, there was a clear goal: to rank various datasets based on their distance from another dataset. What are you trying to do here? If you intend to plot them, then you need to say that. If you want to rank them based on their distance from a third dataset, you need to say that and provide the reference dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Distance of distributions (dataset) from a reference dataset"

Sum-of-squares seems easiest:

```r
quants <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 51)
ref <- quantile(tt, quants)
sumsq <- sapply(list(gg=gg, ff=ff, ps=ps), function(z) sum( (quantile(z, quants) - ref)^2 ))
sumsq
#        gg        ff        ps 
# 76290.859 29150.399  4237.075
```

So `ps` is the "closest" distribution/dataset from your reference `tt`.

Visual confirmation of this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
alldat <- rbind(data.frame(id="ff",x=ff), data.frame(id="gg",x=gg), data.frame(id="ps",x=ps), data.frame(id="tt",x=tt))
ggplot(alldat, aes(x, color = id)) + stat_ecdf(geom = "step")
```

[image: comparison of ECDF curves]